# How to free NULL pointer after using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, null, free

For example, i have the code below for calculate the size of pointer (like an array in this case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **ptr;
void init() {
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int *)*5);
    if(!ptr){
        printf("cannot malloc, \n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if(!ptr[i]){
            printf("cannot malloc, ptr[%d]\n", i);
            return;
        }
    }
    ptr[4] = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    init();
    int count = 0;
    while(ptr[count] != NULL) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("size of ptr = %d\n", count);
}
```

## IDEA:

Add NULL pointer at the and of array in `init()` function, then using `while` loop to calculate the size by increasing the `count` until meet the NULL pointer. **Is it a bad idea ?**

## The question;

As i know, for `free(pointer)` function, if `pointer` is NULL, nothing occurs. So, **How to free `ptr[4]`?**

I try to free this pointer:

```
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        free(ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);
```

Then verify by Valgrind

```
==2957== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==2957==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2957==    by 0x108775: init (test2.c:12)
==2957==    by 0x1087E1: main (test2.c:22)
==2957== 
==2957== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2957==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==2957==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2957==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2957==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2957==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

One thing i can try is to use `realloc` (i know `realloc(PTR, 0)` is not equivalent to `free(PTR)`):

```
ptr[4] = realloc(ptr[4], 0);
```

But there are still the memory-leaks when i test by Valgrind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You malloc some memory, store that value in `ptr[4]`, then overwrite `ptr[4]` with `NULL`.  This is where your memory leak occurs.  Nothing you do after that can recover the lost memory.

You'll want to stop your loop at 4 (instead of 5).

Comment: I will do sth with `ptr[0,1, 2, 3]`, `ptr[4] = NULL` just for stopping `while` loop

Comment: I understand why there is memory-leak here. I just want to know how we can free the memory for ptr[4]. With your answer, i can assume that there is nothing to do for freeing the pointer, right ?

Comment: @Hitokiri There is nothing to do to free the memory because no memory was allocated.